# Embed SVG from JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, svg

I'm really new in web development, I'm currently practicing with the AngularJS framework since it's so easy to work with for a beginner like me.

I'm pulling JSON data through an API using $http.get

I have a field that's `"<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwg... />"`

Is it possible for me to embed this into html somehow to actually show the image? Since the field already contains the  bit, I tried to do this: <{{field_427}} /> but it's not working. Anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: was it really necessary to paste the entirety of the data?

Comment: Yep, that's a bit inordinate.

Comment: What'd I tell ya, I'm a scrub! I edited the code out for readability, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it easier to just return the svg directly without `<img>`?
You should be able to use

```
<object data="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0i...."></object>
```

In angularjs this would be that:

```
<object data="{{base64String}}"></object>
```

Creating a directive using link should be not too complicated. You can find enough examples for that.

The solution to your problem would be to bind to

```
// inject $sce in controller
// Load html
$scope.svg = $sce.trustAsHtml(imgTagWithHtml)

// In view
<span ng-bind-html="svg"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning html from an API should be avoided if you control both ends since it has to be trusted as in Marc's comment. Instead, return the base64 data and leave off the img html tag. Then use the scope to apply the src to the view. Alternatively, create an HTTP Get endpoint that returns the image with a 200 response and the image data.